# How can I add a string of Length One with multiple titles?

Tags: r, string, vector, survival-analysis, gtsummary

Current Code:

```
survfit(Surv(time, DEATH_EVENT) ~ 1, data = HF %>% filter(age <= 70)) %>% 
  tbl_survfit(
    times = c(150,200),
    label_header = "**150 Day survival (95% CI)**"
  )
```

Output:
[image]

How can I add two separate titles to indicate survival times at 150 & 200?

**The following code gives me an error:**

```
survfit(Surv(time, DEATH_EVENT) ~ 1, data = HF %>% filter(age <= 70)) %>% 
  tbl_survfit(
    times = c(150,200),
    label_header = c("**150 Day survival (95% CI)**", "**200 Day survival (95% CI)**")
  )
```

> Error: `statistic=` and `label_header=` arguments must be strings of length one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the function's help file. The first example solves this issue: you need to use glue-syntax to dynamically insert the day number into the headers.

https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_survfit.html

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(survival)

# Example 1 ----------------------------------
# Pass single survfit() object
tbl_survfit_ex1 <- tbl_survfit(
  survfit(Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ trt, trial),
  times = c(12, 24),
  label_header = "**{time} Month**"
)
```

[image]